# Laravel, Inertia y Vue 3, error en los "mensajes flash"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertia.js

En el controlador estoy pasando el mensaje de esta manera

```
return Redirect::route('residentes.index')->with('success', 'Residente Creado Exitosamente');
```

En la clase"handleInertiaRequest" tengo configurada la función de esta manera

```
public function share(Request $request)
     {
         return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
             'flash' => function () use ($request) {
                 return [
                     'success' => $request->session()->get('success'),
                     'error' => $request->session()->get('error'),
                 ];
             },
         ]);
     }
```

Finalmente estoy capturando y mostrando el mensaje en el componente "AppLayout" de esta manera

```
<div v-if="$page.props.flash.success">
    {{ $page.props.flash.success }}
</div>
```

El problema es que el mensaje aparece y desaparece rápidamente. No se mantienen en la interfaz de usuario ¿Alguien sabe cual podría ser el problema? Muchas gracias desde ya